# Problem with pasting table from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I use a macro for over 2 years with no problems. The macro is simple - copy a table from an Excel file and paste it into a Word document. For a few days, I am struggling with a problem - after starting the macro

> error 4198 is occurring.

After clicking Debug VBA highlights such part of the code:

```
myDoc.Paragraphs(17).Range.PasteExcelTable _
LinkedToExcel:=False, _
WordFormatting:=False, _
RTF:=False
```

When I click Continue, the macro is going to the end with no additional problems until the next iteration.

Here is the entire macro:

```
Sub Agent_info()

Dim w As MailMerge
Dim a As Integer
Dim NumberOfFiles As Integer
Dim sFileName As String
Dim xlTable As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table
Dim komorka As String

Dim my_xl As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

'NumberOfFiles = 3
NumberOfFiles = InputBox("Ile pism przygotować?", "Pytanie")

On Error GoTo ERR_Handler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Visible = True
   
    Set w = ActiveDocument.MailMerge

    w.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstDataSourceRecord
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim xlPath As String
    xlPath = "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\ZAŁĄCZNIKI.xlsx"
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set my_xl = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    Worksheets("info").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wysyłka maili\Załączniki do wysłania", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wysyłka maili\Załączniki do wysłania"
    End If
    If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wysyłka maili\Załączniki do wysłania\INFO", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wysyłka maili\Załączniki do wysłania\INFO"
    End If
    If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma"
    End If
    If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Pliki tymczasowe", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Pliki tymczasowe"
    End If
     
    For a = 1 To NumberOfFiles
        
        On Error Resume Next
    
        Set xlApp = GetObject("Excel.Application")
        Err.Clear
        If xlApp Is Nothing Then Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            MsgBox "Microsoft Excel could not be found, aborting."
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        
        komorka = ActiveCell.Address
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "Suma"
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Set xlTable = Excel.Range(komorka, ActiveCell)
        xlTable.Copy
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "Zaległość"
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        Loop
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        
    
    
        With w
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = a
                .LastRecord = a
            End With
        
            .Execute Pause:=False
        
        End With
        Dim katalog As String
        Dim folder As String
        Dim sciezka1 As String
        Dim sciezka2 As String
        Dim PDF As String
        Dim PDF2 As String
        Dim nazwaPisma As String
        Dim nazwa1 As String
        Dim nazwa2 As String
        katalog = w.DataSource.DataFields("NAZWA_PLIKU").Value
        folder = w.DataSource.DataFields("DATA_DO_PISMA_rrrrmmdd").Value
        'folder = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
        If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog
        End If
        If Len(Dir("C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog & "\" & folder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog & "\" & folder
        End If
        'MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog
        'MkDir "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog & "\" & folder
        nazwaPisma = " informacja o stanie zaległości z dnia "
                
        sciezka1 = "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Pliki tymczasowe\" & w.DataSource.DataFields("AGENT").Value & nazwaPisma & w.DataSource.DataFields("DATA").Value & ".docx"
        sciezka2 = "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog & "\" & folder & "\" & w.DataSource.DataFields("AGENT").Value & nazwaPisma & w.DataSource.DataFields("DATA").Value & ".docx"
        PDF = "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wezwania\Wezwania\Gotowe pisma\" & katalog & "\" & folder & "\" & w.DataSource.DataFields("AGENT").Value & nazwaPisma & w.DataSource.DataFields("DATA").Value & ".pdf"
        PDF2 = "C:\Users\jbalce\Desktop\Wysyłka maili\Załączniki do wysłania\INFO\" & w.DataSource.DataFields("AGENT").Value & nazwaPisma & w.DataSource.DataFields("DATA").Value & ".pdf"
        ActiveDocument.Parent.ScreenUpdating = False
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs _
            FileName:=sciezka1, _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, _
            LockComments:=False, _
            Password:="", _
            AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
            WritePassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
            EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
            SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
            SaveFormsData:=False, _
            SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
        ActiveDocument.Close
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
        Err.Clear
        If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        WordApp.Visible = True
        WordApp.Activate
        Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(sciezka1)
        myDoc.Paragraphs(17).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False
        'If Err.Number = 4198 Then
            'MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        'End If
        
        Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
        WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
        WordTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        Set PasteSheet = Nothing
        Documents(myDoc).SaveAs _
            FileName:=sciezka2, _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, _
            LockComments:=False, _
            Password:="", _
            AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
            WritePassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
            EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
            SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
            SaveFormsData:=False, _
            SaveAsAOCELetter:=False
        
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            OutputFileName:=PDF2, _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
            OpenAfterExport:=False, _
            OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
            Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
            From:=1, To:=1, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
            IncludeDocProps:=True, _
            KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
            DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
            UseISO19005_1:=False
            
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            OutputFileName:=PDF, _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
            OpenAfterExport:=False, _
            OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
            Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
            From:=1, To:=1, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
            IncludeDocProps:=True, _
            KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, _
            DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, _
            UseISO19005_1:=False
        Documents(myDoc).Close
           
        w.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
   
    Next
   
END_Handler:

    Application.Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
    Exit Sub

ERR_Handler:
   
    MsgBox Err.Description
   
    Resume END_Handler:
End Sub
```

Comment: Posting a single line of code without any context doesn't enable anyone to reproduce your issue, or see what the cause could be. Also, nobody memorises error codes so always post the error description. Use the [edit link below your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72454590/edit) to add the required details.

Comment: Error 4198 can occur when whatever is in the clipboard cannot be pasted using that command (e.g. a shape object). So check what you have in the clipboard using an ordinary paste.

Comment: Guys, I pasted the entire macro to my question.